# How can I select an nth child without knowing the parent element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I can't figure out a way of selecting the nth element, last element, or first element in cases where I don't know the parent element. `nth-child` exists, but only for children, for example:

```
<div>
   <p>One</p>
   <p>Two</p>
</div>
```

`p:last-child` selects the "Two" paragraph, and `p:first-child` selects the "One" paragraph. But what about when I have dynamic code and have no idea what the parent name is, or even what the parent really is (may be a div, span, anchor, ul, etc.)?

For example:

```
<youdontknowwhat!>
   <p class="select-me">One</p>
   <p class="select-me">Two</p>
</youdontknowwhat!>
```

How do I select the second paragraph here? (I'm unable to select `youdontknowwhat!` since I really don't know what element it is (it's just a hypothetical name).

Why are there `first-child`, `last-child`, and `nth-child` selectors and NO `:first`, `:last`, `:nth` (like `.select-me:first`)?

Comment: How would `:first` be different from `:first-child`? Every HTML element is a child of some other element in the DOM except `<html>` which is the root element.

Comment: It'd be since you don't know the parent element.

Comment: "Why no :first, :last and :nth selectors".  Exactly!  WHY THE HELL NOT?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> How would `:first` be different from `:first-child`? Every HTML element is a child of some other element in the DOM except `<html>` which is the root element. – BoltClock
>
> It'd be since you don't know the parent element. – fomicz

You don't need to know the parent element for `:first-child` or `:nth-child()` to work. *They will just work*, even if you don't specify the parent element.

The following selector is guaranteed to match any appropriate `.select-me` element regardless of what its parent element is:

```
.select-me:nth-child(2)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
*  p:nth-child(2)
```

of course it's better if you can specify the parent selector (for a matter of performance)

Comment: Isn't it poting to p's child, not the p itself? For example what if I have <img src="something.png">? Will * img:nth-child(2) also work?

Comment: @fomicz: You're misunderstanding the `*-child` selectors. See my answer.

Comment: The universal selector can be omitted because `nth-child` implies that `p` must be a child (direct descendant) of something else.