# Trying to use first-child pseudo class selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following CSS which isn't working for me.

```
table.fields tr > td:first-child { padding-right: 50px; }
```

The `HTML` is like the following:

```
    <table class="fields">
         <tbody>
              <tr>
                   <td> text... </td>
                   <td> another td elem... </td>
              </tr>
         </tbody>
   </table>
```

I want to apply the padding to the first `<td>` element but not the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments of the first answer, my lucky guess ended up solving the problem:
Use: `table.fields tr > tr` **instead** of `table.fields tr > td:first-child`

P.S: As I said, it might have been worth trying, and it was! Lucky me haha!

Comment: I think what OP tried was `table.fields tr:first-child > td`, because `tr > tr:first-child` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

**This was posted before stevebot fixed the question.** Leaving my post here for the sake of its comments.

---

Your table has no `fields` class. Change it to this and your CSS selector should pick it up.

```
<table class="fields">
```

Comment: oops sorry, I forgot to put that on there, I did actually have that class applied in my code and it still isn't working in FF3

Comment: shouldn't it be `tr:first-child`? idk..can't really remember but it might be worth trying

Comment: @stevebot: The padding should work, there should be a minimum gap of 50 pixels between the text in your first cell and the middle border. What do you see? Try adding a border to your table.

Comment: @JCOC611: Nope because `:first-child` describes the child, not the parent. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195161/css3-any-way-to-select-nth-element-straight/4195253#4195253) for an explanation.

Comment: @BoltClock In Firebug, I don't see the class being applied to the first td element. I also don't visually see any indication of the class being applied.

Comment: @stevebot: It works for me if I only apply that style and nothing else. Could you paste your other table styles into your question?

Comment: @BoltClock Sorry I think I might have confused you. I wanted to apply the padding to the <td> element and not it's content. The word cell is an ambiguous way to state that.  JCOC611 ended up having the solution that I needed.

Comment: @JCOC611: You should post that as your answer. I'll keep mine here for the sake of the comments. @stevebot: no problem, glad you solved it.