# How can I set css for a class in a class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

With this HTML code.

```
<div class="noote">
    <p class="first admonition-title">Noote</p>
    <p class="last">Let's noote.</p>
</div>
```

How can I set the color of Noote to be red with css?
I mean, how can I set something for (div class="noote") and (p class="first") under it with css?

Comment: do you want to set all DIVs with the class "noote" which have a P with the class "first" in it red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div.note{
   ...
}
```

Refers to the div element that has the class note.

```
p.first{
    ...
}
```

Refers to the p element that has the class first.

```
div.note p.first{
    ...
}
```

Refers to the p element inside note that has the class first.

In addition, if you want to set an element child without setting a class to it,

```
div.note p:first-child{
    /* it refers to the first p that contains noote */
}
```

Comment: OP is asking how to refer to `.first` *inside* `.noote`, not just separately.

Comment: And no, that is not the correct way to use `:first-child`. The correct way is `div.note p:first-child`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195161/css3-any-way-to-select-nth-element-straight/4195253#4195253 for details.

Comment: I dint't understand it by reading the first time :) thanks for the correction :) ..I'm going to update my answer

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
/*this will apply for the element with class first 
inside the element with class noot */

.noote .first{    
    color:red;
}

/* If you wanted to apply a rule for both individually
you can do: */

.noote, .first{    
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@amosrivera's got it.

It's worth nooting that descendant selectors require more CPU.  I always use more specific rules where possible.  So instead of

```
.noote .first{
    backgorund:red;
}
```

You could say

```
.noote > .first{
    backgorund:red;
}
```

A nominal difference in most cases, but still a good habit.

**Really?**

> Descendant selectors are
>   inefficient... The less specific the
>   key, the greater the number of nodes
>   that need to be evaluated.
>
> — [Google "Let's make the web
>   faster" docs](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html)

And

> Descendent selectors are a major slow
>   down to the Safari browser
>
> — [John Sykes, May 2008](http://blog.archive.jpsykes.com/152/testing-css-performance-pt-2/)

Some performance tests show [little impact](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/), and most writers agree that it only makes a difference on very large documents.

But mainly, I'm just going with my programmer instinct — say what you mean, and no more.

Comment: this looks interesting indeed, do you have a link that proves this performance difference?