# I need help with using first-child and last-child CSS selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a three column layout nested within a row. I want to add a border to the right of every column except the last one. I also want to remove the left padding and replace it with a left margin from the first column, and remove the right padding and replace it with a right margin from the last column. I tried using the `first-child` and `last-child` selectors but they don't work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
#row {
}

.box {
    border-right: 1px dotted #e1e1e1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 139px;
}

#row div:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#row div:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-right: 0;
}

<div class="row">

    <div class="box">
        <h3>First Title</h3>
        <div>Stuff</div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <h3>Middle Title</h3>
        <div>Stuff</div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <h3>Last Title</h3>
        <div>Stuff</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a "`mdl`" class to the middle column and only apply margin to that one?

Comment: @Marcel, not really. It would be a stopgap solution, which is not what I'm looking for. I want to address this issue regardless of the number of columns!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is because `row` is a class not an id. change your css to:

```
.row {
}

.box {
    border-right: 1px dotted #e1e1e1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 139px;
}

.row div:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.row div:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Irritatingly, no version of IE supports `:last-child` at this time. IE9 does. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: @JamWaffles, is there a way around this limitation?

Comment: well you can make another css sheet just for IE and use some IE hacks found online to navigate around it.

Comment: Well, you could add a class to the last row and set that to have no padding or whatever, or you could use jQuery... All in all, some ugly stuff. I hate IE more and more every day.

Comment: >breaks down and cries< I can't take this anymore. I can't web develop with IE in this miserable world >:-(

Answer (score 2):

What about styling all the columns the same and giving the container negative margin on the right side?

Demo: [**jsfiddle.net/Marcel/aqmjn**](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/aqmjn/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#row div:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

This block of code is in reference to the last

```
<div>stuff</div>
```

. You are referencing the children of the div you are selecting.

What you want is

```
.row:last-child
```

Comment: -1 You're misunderstanding `:*-child` pseudo-classes. They describe the element that you attach them to, not its children. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195161/css3-any-way-to-select-nth-element-straight/4195253#4195253