# Select main wrapper

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can select the first container div, which is direct desendent of body with css?

I have tried

```
body:first-child{
     background:red;
}
```

This does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body div:first-child{
 background:red;
}
```

Update: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aYez2/)** demo

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but seems to select all div's that are first children.

Comment: This seems to have worked.                                           body:first-child div{
 background:red;
}

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by your comment. The example selects the first div child element of the body tag. What isn't that doing for you?

Comment: It selects all div's in the entire body that are first-children of another div. I want to select just the first div,  wrapper

Comment: @jamjam If you have any other divs deeper in your page, you'll need to actually make use of the child selector `>`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/4195253/106224 for how `:first-child` works.