# Spree themeing with Deface: What css selector will select the first h3 from this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, css-selectors, spree

I'm trying to theme a Spree site using deface. Deface uses css selectors to select elements and then modify them, so in theory if you've only got experience with css2/3 and have any ideas then please leave an answer below.

Given [this file](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/auth/app/views/spree/users/show.html.erb#L1) (snippet below of this below) How do a select the very first `h3` element. Unfortunately, deface works in isolation so there's no surrounding elements to bind to, otherwise I could do something like `.container h3:first-child` and be done with it, it also means that something like `h3:first-child` doesn't work, as this would select the first child of the h3 element.

Html snippet:

```
<h3><%= accurate_title %></h3>

<div data-hook="account_summary">
  <dl id="user-info">
    <dt><%= t(:email) %></dt>
    <dd><%= @user.email %> (<%= link_to t(:edit), spree.edit_account_path %>)</dd>
  </dl>
</div>

<div data-hook="account_my_orders">

  <h3><%= t(:my_orders) %></h3>
  <% if @orders.present? %>
    <table class="order-summary">
```

Any ideas or thoughts appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it also means that something like `h3:first-child` doesn't work, as this would select the first child of the h3 element.

Wrong. It selects [the `h3` element **if it's the first child**, not **the first child of** the `h3` element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4195253/106224).

Anyway, if deface treats `h3` as one of three root elements as you seem to imply (which doesn't really make sense to me), try this:

```
h3:root
```

Or if it actually takes your HTML snippet and places it within some anonymous root element, you could try using this:

```
:root > h3:first-child
```

The [`:root` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#root-pseudo) is fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong in the context of standard CSS, but in the context of Deface/Nokogiri, unfortunately, I'm right - You can verify that here: http://deface.heroku.com/ That said, your suggestion of h3:root works! So I'm happy! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, sorry may I know what exactly is the `h3:root` solution? I have the same problem as well when I want to target the first `code[erb-silent]` of a file :(

Comment: @daemonsy: It selects `h3` if it's the (or a) top-level element. You can try `code[erb-silent]:root` (is `erb-silent` supposed to be an attribute? I'm not sure).

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn. Doesn't seem to work :(. I've tried both `code[erb-silent]:root` and `code[erb-silent]:first-of-type`. Erm, deface converts the <% %> into <code erb-silent> if I'm not wrong. Hence the attribute selector.

Comment: @daemonsy , do you have a SO question set up for your query? Might help to have a look at the code, and if I can, I'll try and answer it.