# First-child selector within table

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have created a page which is a login portal to three separate websites. On this page, I have displayed the three login portals to said websites. I am trying to style it all with css and as few classes as possible (I need to fine tune my css skills).

What I have created is a table with three rows and two columns called loginPortals:

```
<table class="loginPortals">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Picture 1</td>
            <td>Login form 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Picture 2</td>
            <td>Login form 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Picture 3</td>
            <td>Login form 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've only just begun the styling of the table, so it's very incomplete, however I'm struggling already. This is simplified, because I don't know exactly how it's going to look. Basically though, I want a border of some sort appearing between each row. The following doesn't quite achieve this as I had wanted:

```
.loginPortals{
    width:100%;
}
    .loginPortals tbody:first-child td{
        border-top:1px solid #000;
    }
    .loginPortals tbody tr td{
        border-bottom:1px solid #000;
        padding:1em 0;
    }
```

The first-child selector isn't working as I had thought it would. It is applying the top border to all the cells in all the rows. This is causing the line thickness to double in the middle of the rows.

How do I fix this so that the top border is only applied to the top row without creating extra classes or applying any inline style.

Thank you!
Joe

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/6h8cD/ . could you show us the webpage where it is messing up?

Comment: What is the visual effect you are trying to achieve? And are you using `border-collapse:collapse` on the table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your table borders need to be set to collapse:

```
.loginPortals{
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

You can then omit the `:first-child` rule and just apply top and bottom borders for all your rows:

```
.loginPortals tbody tr td{
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    padding:1em 0;
}
```

Also, just for your information, this selector:

```
.loginPortals tbody:first-child td
```

Means:

> Select any `td` element
>   within a `tbody`
>   that is the first child of its parent.

And not:

> Select any `td` element
>   within the first child of a `tbody`.

So since the `tbody` is the first and only child of `.loginPortals`, all the `td` elements in all their `tr` parents will be selected. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4195253/106224) for a visual explanation. You probably wanted this selector:

```
.loginPortals tbody tr:first-child td
```

But that's not necessary because all you have to do is collapse your table borders.

Comment: Thank you. This works exactly as I am hoping for. I would accept your answer as *the* answer, but I have to wait 4 minutes. I'll accept it later. And I did not know that about the selectors! Ha. Thanks again for that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have 3 forms and only want two lines - that's what I took from `I want a border of some sort appearing between each row` if that's the case, try this.

```
.loginPortals tr:first-child td{
    border-top:none;
}
.loginPortals tbody tr td{
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    padding:1em 0;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u4v3Z/

Comment: Funnily enough it wasn't, I was wanting to remove the double thickness between cells, but having looked at your fiddle as to what it looks like I think I might make it like this haha. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work...

```
td {border-top:1px solid #000;}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to improve your CSS skills you should immediately stop using tables for layout.

Second, the `:first-child` pseudo class affects elements that are the first child of their parents. So since you only have one `tbody` element and it is the first child of the `table` writing `tbody` or `tbody:first-child` will yield the same results.

Edit: I think what you might be after here is `tr:first-child td` (you only want the table cells in the first table row to have a top border).

To solve your problem you could just go with `border-bottom` on all `td`s, unless you need a border in the top as well in which case you could set that border on the actual `table` *or* you could give all the `td`s a `border-top` *and* `border-bottom`. This of course renders a double border as you describe, but you can make the borders of a table collapse using `border-collapse: collapse`.

So in short: `table {border-collapse: collapse}`. But don't use tables for layout.