# :first-letter CSS - restricting it to first letter of an article in a template

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm having trouble targetting just the first letter in this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gB94x/

Obviously the "read more" isn't supposed to have the drop cap too.

The HTML can't be changed, it's part of a fixed template.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.od_article>p` references all `p` tags that are immediate children of `.od_article` and therein lies your problem.  You only want the first `p` tag.  Change `.od_article>p:first-letter` to `.od_article>p:first-of-type:first-letter` as in the updated fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/gB94x/1/

**UPDATE:**

I don't believe IE7 supports the `:first-of-type` unfortunately.  I'm not sure if it supports `:first-child` either but for reference, `:first-child` matches if the element it's applied to is the first child of its parent.

I can't think of a workaround off the top of my head but looking at the HTML the `p` you want to change the first letter for has the class `CaptionPic1`.  If the first paragraph will always have this class, just use that, so `.CaptionPic1:first-letter`.

Comment: That's great thanks. I was trying .od_article>p:first-child:first-letter too. I didn't know first-of-type was a thing! Cheers again.

Comment: Is there a workaround for ie7? :first-letter works, but :first-of-type doesnt

Comment: @acowley On the other hand, IE7 has less than 3% market share globally according to statcounter so consider how much time you want to spend appealing to that tiny minority.

Comment: You're right, and I wouldn't ususally worry about it, but its for an internal newsletter/intranet page and guess which browser the majority of the organisation is still using? ;) Insane I know! i'll just use an ie7 specific hack. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @acowley haha! "You are the 3%!" :-P

Comment: IE7 supports `:first-child`, but if the first `p` isn't the first child it will never match.

Comment: Also, your description of `:first-child` is incorrect. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4195253/106224 for an explanation. Once you understand what it *actually* does, a solution immediately comes to mind - see my answer for an example of how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector:

```
.od_article>p:first-letter
```

Is trying to apply styles to the first letter of *every* `p` child whose parent has the class `od_article`.

You can either use this to get the first `p` element:

```
.od_article>p:first-of-type:first-letter
```

Or, if you need to support older browsers like IE7 and IE8, which don't understand CSS3 pseudo-classes such as `:first-of-type`, and you know that the first child is always an `h1` and the first `p` always follows that `h1` in your HTML structure, you can use `:first-child` with a sibling selector like this:

```
.od_article>h1:first-child+p:first-letter
```

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/gB94x/6)

Comment: @acowley Interestingly, I'm seeing that if you insert additional elements in IE7, it won't update the element that matches `+`. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html