# can you use the fist-child pseudo selector multiple times in one css selection

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select the first div within the fist li of a ul, is there an easier way then this? ...i cannot modify the html and add a id.

thanks for your input!

```
#subNav>li:first-child>div:first-child
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it work?

Comment: Sure you can and it will work. Just give it a try

Comment: it works but it seems messy.. can i simplify it?

Comment: Simplify? You're lucky you can use direct descendant and first-child selectors at all! Otherwise it would be a lot uglier.

Comment: @TheZ: Ah, such are the times...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you already have there is as good as it gets. I don't see anything messy about it — you *do* want *specifically only* the first `div` child of the first `li` child of `#subNav` after all...

Comment: ok well that is good to hear, i was hoping there may be a 2-child or second-child selector way that someone know about..

Comment: @codelove: Not sure what you mean by second-child selector... do you mean something like nested or recursive `:first-child` selectors? I remember that being tossed about in the mailing list here: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Mar/0531.html but that was just an idea

Comment: cool! yes a -recursive selector is exactly what i was hoping to find, thanks for the link, i will use the first-child selector multiple times until, if ever, this -recursive selector becomes a reality.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is valid, you are selecting each first child of `#subNav>li` and inside those each first child of div element.

Comment: That's not how `:first-child` works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195161/any-way-to-select-nth-element-straight/4195253#4195253