# How to target the first <a> tags in a <ul>

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this markup:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>Target Me!</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a>And Not me.</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a>Target Me!</a>
         </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, I was wondering if I how can I target the  tags that are the direct children of the outer `<ul>` which doesn't includes the `<a>` tags that are inside the `<ul>` which is inside an `<li>` (I hope it doesn't sound confusing)

I have tried:

```
div ul li > a { border: 1px solid #000; }
```

but it still targets all the `<a>`s.

Can somebody help me with this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div > ul > li > a { border: 1px solid #000; }
```

would work in your case.

However, I would rather make use of a class to achieve this.

Comment: I disagree with you there. Theres no need for a class to be used in this instance. Your rule would be much better than a class.

Comment: The only real reason I can come up with for using a class solely to make up for the use of child selectors is for IE6 support...

Answer (score 0):

alternatively

```
div ul li:first-child { border: 1px solid #000; }
```

but this'd only work if your desired `<a>` truly is the first child of that `<li>`.

Comment: 1) The second `li > a` in the top `ul` wouldn't match 2) `li:first-child` doesn't mean "first child of `li`" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195161/css3-any-way-to-select-nth-element-straight/4195253#4195253

Comment: This will apply the border to the li element not the a.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work:

```
div ul li > a:first-child { border: 1px solid #000; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the first-child pseudo-class like this

```
div ul > li:first-child > a:first-child
```

THis will only target the first li that is child to ul and then only the first child anchor element.  BUt this is very convoluted you are better off using a class here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsbin.com/ecenan

basically the CSS should be

`div > ul > li > a { border: 1px solid #000; }`