# Baffling pseudo-element syntax with :first-child and :first-letter

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I was playing around with CSS selectors, when I ran into a weird situation.

If I use :first-child pseudo-element I need to prepend it with a space for it to work, If I don't it will not work. However with :first-letter pseudo-element situation is reverse, it will work only if it is not prepended by space.

I find it quite inconsistent as those are both pseudo elements. Initially I thought it may be just IE10 issue, but I checked with Chrome and Firefox with the same results. Is there something I am missing? Is there a reason for this behavior?

Here, is the compact sample reproducing the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    * { color: red; }
    #article1 :first-child { color: deepskyblue; }
    article :last-child { color: darkmagenta; }
    #firstLetter:first-letter { color: darkslateblue; }
    #firstLine:first-line { color: darkslateblue; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <article id="article1">
        <div>E :first-child </div>
        <div>E :last-child </div>
    </article>                        
    <div id="firstLetter">:first-letter</div>
    <div id="firstLine">:first-line</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `first-child` doesn't mean the first child of the element, it's an element that is its parent's first child.

Comment: Well, there you go... you are correct, makes sense. So basically you need a space with pseudo-classes, but you cannot have it with pseudo-elements

Comment: @SebastianK: Not really, you can attach pseudo-classes or pseudo-elements to any selector with or without the space. They just don't mean the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your confusion comes from the fact that `:first-child` and `:last-child` are [pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-class-selectors), not pseudo-elements. Each of them mean the first and last child of its parent respectively, but the element you attach them to represents the *child*, not the *parent*. A pseudo-class is a *description* of a certain element, if you will, just like an ID selector describes an element with that ID or an attribute selector describes an element with that attribute. So, the selector `E:first-child` means `E` that is the first child of its parent — whatever that parent may be — but not the first child *of* `E`.

The selector `#article1:first-child` should match `#article1` since it's the first child of `body`, but it will not match the `div` that is the first child *of* `#article1`. `#article1 :first-child` matches the `div` because, well, it's the first child whose parent happens to be `#article1`.

On the other hand, `:first-letter` and `:first-line` work because they match the first letter and first line *of* each element respectively. This is what is meant by a [pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-element-selectors); a virtual element (not represented in the DOM) that's generated as a member *of* some other element.

Note that this doesn't mean you can or cannot use the space with one or the other. You can use any combinator with any pseudo-class or pseudo-element selector, or attach it to another chain of simple selectors. They just mean different things when used with or without a combinator, which is why you're seeing different results.

Another explanation of pseudo-classes versus pseudo-elements can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195161/any-way-to-select-nth-element-straight/4195253#4195253).

If you don't need to support IE8 and older, you should represent pseudo-elements using double colons to help you distinguish them from pseudo-classes, so `::first-letter` and `::first-line` instead of `:first-letter` and `:first-line`. This notation is introduced in the new [Selectors module](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements).

Comment: Yeah, that explains what I needed to know thanks. I was under impression that both first-child adn first-letter were pseudo-elements whcich was incorrect.