# Remove comma of the last dd before every dt embeded using :after pseudo element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I use CSS to add a commas after description (dd) elements, except for the last one before each new description term? For example:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Term</dt>
    <dd>Description</dd>
    <dd>Description</dd>
    <dd>Description</dd>      <!-- No comma needed here -->
    <dt>Term</dt>
    <dd>Description</dd>
    <dd>Description</dd>
    <dd>Description</dd>      <!-- No comma needed here -->
</dl>
```

**Note:** I'm looking for a solution that's independent from the number of dd elements preceding a dt.

Adding the comma afer each dd is simple:

```
dd:after
{
content:",\00a0";        /* A comma and a space after each description (dd) */
}
```

But this adds a comma after each dd that immediately precedes a dt as well. dd:last-child:after is obviously of no use here, unless there's some other CSS selector I'm unaware of.

Comment: Assuming you are styling this whole thing inline, why not put the ", " before each `dd` unless it's immediately preceded by a `dt`? (Oh, hang on, linebreaks probably. Nevermind ;) )

Comment: You cannot style, in CSS, an element according to what *follows* it. There might be a workaround that is based on adding content with `:before`, but this depends on how the `dl` as a whole should be styled.

Answer (score 4):

You *cannot use* `:last-child` or `:last-of-type` here, as your elements aren't nested inside a sub parent element.

So you can use `:nth-of-type(3n)`, means we select every 3rd iteration of your `dd` element which is nested under `dl` element.

```
dl dd:nth-of-type(3n):after {
    content:"";
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xXy2J/)

This will be useful if each list of yours has consistent amount of items, if not, than I would suggest you to wrap the list with a sub parent and than you can use `:last-child` or `:last-of-type` pseudo to target them regardless of the number of items they hold.

Or if they aren't dynamic, than you can use like

```
dl dd:nth-of-type(3):after,
dl dd:nth-of-type(8):after {
   content: "";
}

/* Assuming if you have inconsistent list items and 3rd dd and 8th dd 
   are last child of their respective lists.. and you don't  want a sub 
   wrapper element */
```

---

If you want to have more compatible selector, than you can also use adjacent selector `+`..

```
dl dd + dd + dd:after {
    content:"";
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/xXy2J/1/)

But above selector will be good to use if you have 2-3 `dd` elements, more you have, more the selector gets awkward to write, so if you have more items, please refer to the selector I provided you at first place.

> P.S Using `/* No comma needed here */` is an invalid comment in HTML,
>   should use `<!-- Comment goes here -->`.

Comment: Thanks for the demos. Could you give me an example demo of wrapping the list with a sub parent and using :last-child or :last-of-type pseudo? :]

Comment: @MattyPantaloons you welcome, if the answers help you, you can click on the tick beside the answer...

Comment: The only problem with that demo is the description lists only have one dt each. I'm looking for a solution that applies to dl's with more than one dt per list. Not possible?

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is another way if you don't mind adding a little something to your html. And this will work for any number of dd's not just 3.

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/9HjV2/)**

```
<dl>
    <dt>Term</dt>
    <dd>Description</dd>
    <dd data-last-dd="">Description</dd>
    <dt>Term</dt>
    <dd>Description</dd>
    <dd>Description</dd>
    <dd>Description</dd>
    <dd>Description</dd>
    <dd data-last-dd="">Description</dd>
</dl>
```

---

```
dd[data-last-dd]:after{
    content:"";
}
```

Comment: What is the use of `<dd data-last-dd="">` even `<dd data-last-dd>` should work fine?

Comment: Browsers are forgiving, that doesn't mean we should take it for granted.

Comment: You can define `class` instead, it's one and the same thing :) and also, it's valid to use only `data-last-dd`, they are called boolean attributes

Comment: @Mr.Alien - Using `class` is *not* one in the same thing as using `data-*`, as the former does not provide any semantics, except perhaps to the human reading it. `data-*` is intended to provide machine-readable semantic value. However, **I do agree with you that the OP should use `class` instead of `data-*`**, because in this particular case, he needs to select an element to be *styled*, which by definition is "unsemantic".

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, you are allowed to group `dt`'s together with their `dd`'s.

> In order to annotate groups with microdata attributes, or other global
> attributes that apply to whole groups, or just for styling purposes,
> each group in a dl element can be wrapped in a div element. This does
> not change the semantics of the dl element.

(See [HTML Living Standard; 4.4.9 The dl-element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element))

You can use this to force the last `dd` to be a `:last-child`.

**Example:**

```
<dl>
    <div>
        <dt>Drinks</dt>
        <dd>water</dd>
        <dd>coffee</dd>
        <dd>juice</dd>
    </div>
    <div>
        <dt>Snacks</dt>
        <dd>crisps</dd>
        <dd>nuts</dd>
    </div>
<dl>
```

with css:

```
dd:not(:last-child):after {
    content: ", ";
}
```

Now, no comma will be added after *juice*.

Answer (score -5):

Try this:

```
dl:last-child
{
    content:""!important;
}
```

Comment: 1) Unnecessary `!important` for its own sake is a guaranteed downvote 2) `dl:last-child` selects `dl` if it is the last child of its parent. Not the last child of `dl`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195161/any-way-to-select-nth-element-straight/4195253#4195253

Comment: Even *IF* `dl:last-child` selected the last child of `dl` (which it does not), it would not select the last `dd` in an arbitrary group of terms-and-descriptions, for example, a `dd` preceding a `dt`, as the OP wanted.