# How to select an element and its first child without repetition in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, dry

I need to select a particular element and it first child in CSS.

Here is the rule I use right now:

```
#some_element, #some_element:first-child {
    ...
}
```

However, I really doubt that repeating the `id`'s element like that is a good practice.

Is there any better and correct way to do this?

Comment: I know this is not your question but `#some_element:first-child` won't select the first-child of `#some_element`. It will select the `#some_element` if it is also the first-child of its parent.

Comment: Other than the misconception pointed out by Harry, this would be the correct, and shortest, way in css; though I understand that [tag:sass] and [tag:less] might have a syntactic shortcut (which involves a compilation step, and will resolve to the shame selector syntax).

Comment: @Harry Oh, you are right, I always forget this. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you. Please, add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selectors, once corrected:

```
#some_element, #some_element :first-child {
    ...
}
```

Is the shortest way it can be written in CSS; unfortunately CSS has – as yet – has no shortcut syntax to condense the selectors.

Incidentally, your original selector:

```
#some_element, #some_element:first-child
```

Would select the `#some_element` only if that element is a first-child of its parent. The corrected selector – above – has a similar problem in that it will select the `#some_element` element and then *every element* that is a `:first-child` of its parent. Given that, it's possible – though not explicitly identified in your question – that you might wish to further correct your selector to:

```
#some_element, #some_element > :first-child
```

Which will select the `#some_element` element, and *only* the `:first-child` of that element.

Also, to develop the answer a little further, with both SASS, and LESS, you could select the element and its `:first-child` like so:

```
div {
  min-height: 3em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
}
#some_element {
  /* properties of #some_element: */
  background-color: #ffa;
  &, > :first-child {
  /* shared properties of
     #some_element and its first-child: */
    border: 2px solid red;
  }
  > :first-child {
  /* properties of the first-child of
     #some_element: */
    background-color: #f90;
  }
}
```

Which will compile to:

```
div {
  min-height: 3em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
}
#some_element {
  /* properties of #some_element: */
  background-color: #ffa;
}
#some_element,
#some_element > :first-child {
  /* shared properties of
     #some_element and its first-child: */
  border: 2px solid red;
}
#some_element > :first-child {
  /* properties of the first-child of
     #some_element: */
  background-color: #f90;
}
```

Note that I only very, *very* occasionally even look at either SASS or LESS (being a hobbyist I rarely have any need to work with particularly complex layouts that their selector syntax permits), so there *may* be a more concise way to select the `:first-child`.

I also think it's worth noting that, in this instance, neither SASS or LESS offer any increased brevity (though there are potentially many times in which they will).

Comment: I wouldn't call `#some_element, #some_element :first-child` a correction at all - I'd jump straight to `>` - but I can see how someone might think of that as the first step since most people keep getting "child" and "descendant" mixed up.

Comment: There's that, and I had to think for a second about whether to use that approach - rather than jump directly to using the child combinator - but I opted to do so in the end, because the question seems vague as to whether it's all first-children that should be selected or only the first-child of the `#some_element`. I think the ambiguity tends to favour the use of the first-child combinator, but I chose to be 'forgiving' (?) in my reading. But included both, just in case. I don't think it adversely affects the correctness, but you're not the only one that's ambiguous about the 'correction.'

Answer (score 1):

Since a complex selector can only represent one element structure at a time, you will indeed have to reference the element with that ID both times: once for itself, and once for its first child (that which is represented by the `:first-child` pseudo-class instead).

As mentioned, there should be a combinator separating the ID selector and the `:first-child` pseudo, [otherwise they'll both point to the same element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195161/any-way-to-select-nth-element-straight/4195253#4195253):

```
#some_element, #some_element > :first-child
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `:first-child` in this way:

```css
#parent {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.child {
    background: black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.child:first-child {
    background: blue;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no idea what this answer is trying to say.