# How can I select an nth element without knowing the element in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select the first child inside the div with CSS. But I don't know what the element is:

```
<div>
   <youdontknowwhat>One</youdontknowwhat>
   <input>
</div>
```

Something like:

```
div>x:first-child{  }
```

But 'x' is not usable... Any ideas?

A little different from:
[How can I select an nth child without knowing the parent element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195161/how-can-i-select-an-nth-element-without-knowing-the-parent-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select the first child of the `<div>` you can use the following solution:

```css
div > :first-child {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Test #1</p>
  <div>Test #2</div>
</div>
```