# Can't seem to target element with nth-child

Tags: css

I'm trying to target a div with no ID or class, and nth-child seems perfect for this, but I can't seem to get it to work. I even copied the exact selector in Safari's web inspector, but using that still has no effect. Here's what I'm seeing, with the desired div highlighted in the Inspector.

[image: Screenshot of site and code]

I want to eliminate the unneeded space on the bottom of the ticketing box (just below the Add to Cart button) - the third div under "div.card". I'm also throwing in a couple of extra styles that are not overrides, just to make sure I'm reaching the right div, but they aren't displaying.

The selector that Web Inspector provides is

```
#widget > event-ticket-widget > div > div.card > div:nth-child(3)
```

But it simply doesn't work and I'm hitting a wall here... hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867097/why-is-nth-child-selector-not-working) would provide some insight into the problem

Comment: If your site is online, please provide a link. It will be more convenient to give a help.

Comment: Link added below.

Answer (score 0):

NEW ANSWER:

I just realized that this element is inside an iFrame. You *cannot* affect the contents of an iFrame via CSS!

But there is a workaround for this particular situation: You can apply a negative margin to the wrapper of that iFrame, which will make it less high:

```
#elevent-ticket-widget {
    margin-bottom: -150px;
}
```

And if you only want to apply this to that particular page, you can add the page-id class to the selector: `.postid-3896 #elevent-ticket-widget { ... }`

Comment: Thanks Johannes, but my attempt to do the same produced no results for some reason... `#widget div.container-fluid.position-relative.no-padding > div.card > div:nth-child(3) {
 height: 1em !important;
 border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}` 

In fact I don't even see this CSS anywhere in the (safari) Web inspector. What gives?  

BTW, the actual link is:  http://www.vjff.org/events/event/and-then-she-arrived/

Comment: I had seen the link in your screenshot, had already gone to the page and added a new rule with that selector right there in the browser tools, and it worked (in Firefox), so I am really wondering...

Comment: ah, I just discovered that all that is inside an iFrame! You can't affect the contents of an iFrame via CSS! But there *is* a possibility / workaround: I'll add it to my answer in a minute.

Comment: I'm hoping for that workaround! Keep me posted... and thanks!