# CSS first-child not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Facing a weird problem

For the **HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li class="has-item">four</li>
    <li>five</li>
</ul>
```

**This** works:

```
ul li:first-child {
  font-size:30px
}
```

but why doesn't **this**

```
ul li.has-item:first-child {
  font-size:8px
}
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/xx9us2sg/1/

Comment: The fault is, that your `li` with the class `has-item` is not the `first-child` of the `ul`.

Comment: if li:first-child selects the first-child of ul with type li then why doesn't li.has-item:first-child select the first child of ul with type li class .first-item

Comment: @FahadSohail Because that's not how `:first-child` works. See the link I posted above.

Comment: You missunderstand the `first-child` selector. 
The `first-child` selector, selects the first child of the parent. In this case the parent is `ul` and [Here is an Example of what i mean](https://jsfiddle.net/xx9us2sg/5/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `:first-child` pseudo class, like all other `:nth-child()`-related pseudo-classes counts all siblings (i.e., elements having the same parent). Classes are ignored, as they have nothing to do with the DOM structure.

So `:first-child` is always the first sibling.

This...

```
ul li.has-item:first-child {
  font-size:8px
}
```

doesn't work because `.has-item` doesn't represent the `:first-child` of anything. The first child will always be `<li>one</li>`.

Related: [Why is nth-child selector not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41867097/3597276)